# Certain integration technique

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What technique to follow when integration functions in the form:
$$\sin ax\over \sin bx$$
$$\cos ax\over \cos bx$$
$$\sin ax \over \cos bx$$

I do believe that all these forms should have a similar technique to follow.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @DavidQuinn. Do you think it does matter ? I am just curious since I believe that, by the end, we should get some ugly hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Ummm.... we haven't been taught those. So I think we should get elementary functions?

Comment: I really doubt that we should get elementary functions except for very specific cases.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Then maybe the questions given to me were of some specific cases. Never thought of that..... I thought that there would a general technique to all of them. Does $\sin x \over \sin 4x$ happen to be one of those specific cases?

Comment: Well .... I think that we should need to use mutliple angle formulae and go the way Alex M. proposed.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard technique: if both $a$ and $b$ are *even*, then you can transform your integrand into a rational function by the substitution $t = \tan x$. If at least one of $a$ and $b$ is *odd*, then the substitution changes a little bit into $t = \tan \frac x 2$. Mind you, though: the rational function that you get might not be easily integrable!

Comment: Not sure if I get this.... Let us suppose that I have a question: $\sin x \over \sin 4x$ Going according to your technique, I believe I should use the substitution $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$

Comment: @Gummybears: Exactly. Now go on and express $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in terms of $t$ by using that $t = \tan \frac x 2 = \frac {\sin \frac x 2} {\cos \frac x 2}$ and $\sin ^2 \frac x 2 + \cos ^2 \frac x 2 = 1$.

Comment: How to express $sin4x$ in terms of $t$ though?

Comment: @Gummybears: Use the two equations given in the comment above to find out $\sin \frac x 2$ and $\cos \frac x 2$. Next, use that $\sin 4x = 2 \sin 2x \cos 2x = 4 \sin x \cos x (2 \cos^2 x -1)$. Note that a $\sin x$ simplifies with the numerator. The remaining terms decompose as $4 (2 \cos ^2 \frac x 2 -1) \big( 2(2 \cos^2 \frac x 2 -1)^2 -1 \big)$ and now replace by the formulae found for $\sin \frac x 2$ and $\cos \frac x 2$.

Comment: Ohh..... quite a long procedure. I do believe that there's a shorter method. Maybe it's for this case only though... Not sure.

Comment: You are right and, as you wrote *the rational function that you get might not be easily integrable!* which is the case for this one ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry, didn't get you?

Comment: @Gummybears. In fact the case is surprizingly simple. I added in an "answer" which is just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment*

Let us consider the case $$I=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(4x)}\,dx$$ Using the multiple angle formula $$\sin(4x)=4\sin(x)\cos(x)-3\sin^3(x)\cos(x)$$ which simplifies a little as Alex M. explained.

Now, use the tangent half-angle substitution $t=\tan(\frac x 2)$ and, after simplifications, we get $$I=-\int \frac{\left(t^2+1\right)^2}{2 \left(t^6-7 t^4+7 t^2-1\right)}\,dt$$ which, fortunately, decomposes as $$I=\int \Big(-\frac{1}{2 \left(t^2-2 t-1\right)}-\frac{1}{2 \left(t^2+2 t-1\right)}-\frac{1}{4
   (t+1)}+\frac{1}{4 (t-1)} \Big)\, dt$$ which can be done.

Comment: ....... See that all makes sense. Except for the trigonometric identity. I mean how many are there? Any way to do it if we don't know the identity of $sin4x$?

Comment: You know $\sin(a+b)$; from it, you can compute $\sin(2x)=\sin(x+x)$, $\sin(3x)=\sin(2x+x)$ and so on.